# Managing Facebook Session in Android App throughout multiple activities with Facebook SDK 3

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have started using Facebook SDK 3.0. I am using LoginButton widget to login into the Facebook. I am referring Scrumptious sample for doing so. In this sample, one Activity(Where session is being initialized) is hosting multiple Fragments.

But in my app, multiple activities hosting multiple fragments. **First the launcher activity(Where session is being initialized) does the login operation with the LoginButton widget. How can i handle the session when I moved to other activities???**

I found same kind of questions in StackOverFlow, but it has been answered for *deprecated Facebook object*. But **i need answer with respect to LoginButton widget, UiLifecycleHelper and Session.StatusCallback**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must always refer to the unique **Session** class.
Every activity has to take an already opened session from the **Session** class or, if no valid sessions are found, created a new one. The method for doing this is *Session.getActiveSession()*.
Then, in each activity, you add the callback that define the logic related to a session state change.

The [UiLifecycleHelper](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/UiLifecycleHelper/) is a very useful class that can help you manage the session state among the activities lifecycle (for example the onPause() method of this class deal with the removal of the callback added in the activity in which it's called)

Comment: In my launcher activity, the session is being initialized here with the help of Facebook LoginButton widget, UiLifecycleHelper and Session.StatusCallback(same like in Scrumptious sample).

When i moved to second activity, again here i defined a private variable for UiLifecycleHelper and a listener implementation for Session.StatusCallback. To get the already opened sesssion here, i am calling this init() method from onCreate of my activity, where it will execute the `Session.getActiveSession()` and if it is not opened, i  will call `Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(this)`. Is it correct???

Comment: Nope! `openActiveSessionFromCache` open a session only if there is a token cache available. Instead use `Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, sessionCallback)`. I use this method when the session is null and even whene there is a session but it's not opened.

Comment: I probably don't getting some thing, I'm doing as you suggested Session.openActiveSession(this, false, new Session.StatusCallback() {..}); to open a previous session, but that statusCallback and the callback of the uiHelper never never get called

Comment: You have to control very well the session state between activities (and with state I also intend the presence of one or more callback). The uiHelper, for example, removes callback when you call the onPause. You also have to control that there is only one session, so call the `openActiveSession()` only if `getActiveSession()` return null. Obviuous the callback is called only on a session state change. Finally I see that you set false for the allowLoginUi, in this case a new session is created and opened only if there is a token cache available.

Comment: Thank you for the help, real appreciated. yo got my voit. I do call to openActiveSession() just once..Now when I'm doing Session.getActiveSession() I'm always getting session with State CREATED, it should be null in the beginning?

Comment: Stupi stupid me, I accidentally forgot to remove some line that deletes the access token