# Android activity not displaying

Tags: android, android-activity, facebook-android-sdk

I have an application which uses official facebook sdk for downloading facebook albums. Recently, I updated my code to incorporate new FB android sdk 3.0.

My first activity starts FB authentication, requests friends' list and sends the graph id of the selected friend to second activity using an intent.

I have NOT made any changes to code for starting second activity but android.view.windowleaked exception occurred. So I called the progress dialog's dismiss function in the onPause, onStop functions of my first activity. Then the error disappeared.

But the second activity is still not shown foreground. Also there are no exceptions. Here is my code.

```
album_intent = new Intent();
album_intent.putExtra("id",graph_id);
album_intent.putExtra("name",selected_friend.toString());
//album_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(Barebone_fbActivity.this, album_selector.class));
album_intent.setClass(this, album_selector.class);

album_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//Context context = getApplicationContext();
//context.startActivity(album_intent);
try
{
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(album_intent);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I added a toast to second activity's onCreate method. Surprisingly the toast is displayed but the activity itself is not displayed. I have also checked my manifest file and have NOT made any changes. I suspect the FB android SDK 3.0 because they have changed almost everything from login to graph api request.
Please help to find the problem.

All activities in my application implements StatusCallback. Here is lifecycle methods of album_selector activity. The 'call' method of StatusCallback is lengthy so it is not included. Also the second activity extends ListActivity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //locks the screen in portrait mode
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Voila", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.setVisible(true);

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(album_selector.this, "", getText(R.string.loading));

    //pressing back button dismisses the progress dialog
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    //get friend_name and friend_id from the intent which started this activity
    Intent starting_intent = getIntent();
    friend_id = starting_intent.getStringExtra("id");
    friend_name = starting_intent.getStringExtra("name");

    lv = getListView();

    Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed())
    {
        Session session = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, this);
        //Session session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, this, bundle);
        currentSession = session;
    }
    if (currentSession != null && !currentSession.isOpened())
    {
        OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(this).setCallback(this);
        if(openRequest == null)
        {
            openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
            openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(permissions));
            openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
            currentSession.openForRead(openRequest);
        }
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

protected void onStop()
{
    super.onPause();
    album_selector.this.dialog.dismiss();
}

protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    album_selector.this.dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Are you using Facebook SDK 3.0.1?

Comment: Maybe it is better if you add some more info, like the important part of the second activity code. And specify what you mean with "not displayed".. black screen? Some errors?

Comment: @nachodeh yes I'm using Facebook sdk 3.0.1.

Comment: I don't what code to post here. After calling startactivity, the first activity is still on foreground but the toast which I mentioned earlier is shown.

Comment: @rochasdv No I haven't used it yet. I don't know if I change my code to startActivityForResult is going to help.

Comment: Find the problem without code is obvious more difficult. However I suggest you to put some Log message in each method of the activity lifecycle. And also, If I'm not wrong, the toast showed by an activity can remain on screen after the activity is finished.

Comment: @5agado The full code is around 700 lines. Is it allowed to post something that big in Stack Exchange ? If you can share your your email address may be I can send you to the whole code.

Comment: Not the full code of course, only the lines related to the activity lifecycle. However try as I said with some log information.

Comment: @5agado All activities in my application implements com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback. I'm editing my question to show the lifecycle methods of second activity(album_selector).

Comment: I don't think that the Facebook SDK is the cause of the problem. It is really strange that the second activity doesn't show up. First try with `startActivity(album_intent)` without the `getApplicationContext()`, second I don't think that `this.setVisible(true)` is needed. Maybe the problem is in the facebook code of the onCreate method, but again it doesn't make sense that the application return to the first activity.

Comment: @5agado Thank you for your reply. I tried to run my application with getApplicationContext() and this.setVisible(true) removed. Still no luck. Should I add 'Log.e' to all activity lifecycle calls ?

Comment: Yes, better add some Log.e. Also try to remove the Facebook related code from the second activity in order to see if the problem is there. Maybe you can find useful info in [another response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055561/managing-facebook-session-in-android-app-throughout-multiple-activities-with-fac/16062629#16062629) I gave about managing session and callback between multiple activities.

Comment: @5agado Thanks for your suggestion. I just commented out each and every line of code related to FB. Surprisingly the activity is shown. Trying to find out more about the problem. Will reply back soon. My reputation is only 13, so I cannot move this discussion to chat.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where the activity was loading and running but it would not be visible.

The problem was that in the AndroidManifest.XML the activity had a theme defined as NoDisplay:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

Removing the above attribute from the activity made it visible again.

Answer (score 0):

See if your child activity which you want to intent is within another package created by you. If it is, that's the reason it is not recognizing your activity. Refract it out to that location where your parent activity is. And that it.

Answer (score 0):

For future users : If child layout is having `ConstraintLayout` and parent layout is having `RelativeLayout / LinearLayout` then the child will not render.
Check if that is your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turned out to be autofills. Remove any autofills

```
 android:autofillHints=""
```

Answer (score 0):

`.java` file and `.xml` file, try giving these files the same name.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Currently, it's hard to understand how this actually answers the question.

Comment: The same thing was happening to me, then I noticed that the `Activity` which had XML file and java file with the same name, didn't have this issue. 

And the one which had this issue solved after I changed its name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the second activity was not shown. The toast given in the second activity was displayed !

this is a section of code of second activity.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayAge">
```

After reading this post I realised that the line

```
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
```

was displayed in gray whereas the other schema links were shown in green. So I copied this part again from the main activity xml.

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

After this the line starting showing in green and on running the app the second activity was displayed.